# search and replace regex for JSON string

Tags: regex, json

I have a JSON string of some object.

I want to

- remove all the keys,
- replace each and every key with 'alpha'

at any parent child level or at any child, throughout the whole object with the condition that if key start with 'a' and ends with 'z'.

For example :

i have json string :

```
"{ "a" : { "b" : 4 }, "b" : { "c" : { "d" : "e", "awefz" : { "l" : "c" }  } }, "c" : { "abcz" : "here" } }"
```

after applying regex 1) should get :

```
"{ "a" : { "b" : 4 }, "b" : { "c" : { "d" : "e"  } }, "c" : {} }"
```

after applying regex 2) should get :

```
"{ "a" : { "b" : 4 }, "b" : { "c" : { "d" : "e", "alpha" : { "l" : "c" }  } }, "c" : { "alpha" : "here" } }"
```

I am just looking for those regexes.

I need have only JSONString and regex(to be found) as inputs.

I do not want to loop through keys or recursive loops through levels.
I only want to achieve using regex over JSON string.

Is there any workaround?

Comment: Can you give us an example input and output and your attempt?

Comment: dont want to loop ? only regex ?

Comment: yes.. and of course i was just going to put some examples..

Comment: @koka What do you mean by "of course"? If you were "of course" going to provide examples, then you would already have provided examples. But you didn't...

Comment: I just meant "i forgot", so its mine apologies. please see the edits

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**regex 1:**

```
,?\s*"a[^"]*z"\s*:[^}]+
```

replace with : `''`

output :

```
"{ "a" : { "b" : 4 }, "b" : { "c" : { "d" : "e"} } }, "c" : {} }"
```

demo : http://regex101.com/r/rO0yN0

**regex 2:**

```
a[^"]*z
```

replace with : `alpha`

output :

```
"{ "a" : { "b" : 4 }, "b" : { "c" : { "d" : "e", "alpha" : { "l" : "c" } } }, "c" : { "alpha" : "here" } }"
```

demo : http://regex101.com/r/wB0rC9

Comment: I should say correct, but just little bit of changing characters, for regex1 i have made this http://regex101.com/r/qN5aF7, where i am trying to remove all the key value pairs where key starts with 'i' and ends with 'r'. but the regex did not perfromed well why so?

Comment: It may be  because your regex may only be limited to the objects, not for strings or numbers or just anything. Can you provide a generic regex for matching just anything whether object or string or number or boolean.

Comment: thanks for your help. http://regex101.com/r/vG6pK9 this is i have derived by changing little bit in regex. Please let me know in which cases my derived regex wont work

Comment: also your second regex will perhaps will even replace any where. We want to replace only keys. As You have missed using "" for start and end of key compulsory prefix and postfix as per JSON standard.

Comment: see here :  http://regex101.com/r/oE9nZ9 your regex will fail here, check th 4th line

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the regex you want:

```
"a[^"]*z"\s*:
```

For JSON:

```
{{ "a" : { "b" : 4 }, "b" : { "c" : { "d" : "e", "awefz" : { "l" : "c" } } }, "c" : { "abcz" : "here" } }
```

you will get:

```
{{ "a" : { "b" : 4 }, "b" : { "c" : { "d" : "e", "alpha": { "l" : "c" } } }, "c" : { "alpha": "here" } }
```

http://regex101.com/r/jV0qH0

---

**Update**
As for the other regex you want (removing the keys and values) - I'm afraid it is not possible, since JSON values cannot be expressed as a regular expression (they have balanced curly braces, which cannot be expressed as a regular expression), so you will have to find some other way of doing it.

Comment: good job.. thats for regex 2). I also need for regex 1) that is to remove that key value pair in json string